# Why is the solution to the particular of $y^{(\text{iv})}+2y′′+y=x \cos x$ equal to $x^{2} \sin(x)+x^{3} \cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering why the cosine in this particular solution has $x$ to power 3. I don't understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^{iv}+2y′′+y=x \cos x$$
We first try:
$$y_p=(ax+b) \cos x +(cx+d) \sin x$$

But since the homogeneous solution is:
$$r^4+2r^2+1=(r^2+1)^2=(r-1)^2(r+i)^2=0$$ $$\implies r=\pm i$$
$$y_h=c_1 \cos x +c_2 \sin x +c_3 x \cos x +c_4x\sin x$$
We need to multiply our guess by $x^2$ so that we have :
$$y_p=x^2(ax+b) \cos x +x^2(cx+d) \sin x$$
Since $y_p$ is odd $(y_p(x)=-y_p(-x))$ we can simplify the guess as:
$$y_p=ax^3 \cos x +d x^2\sin x$$
Plug this in the differential equation and find the constants $a$ and $d$.
You should find;
$$\boxed {y_p=-\dfrac {x^3}{24}\cos x +\dfrac {x^2}8 \sin x}$$

Comment: what do you mean $y_{p}$ is odd

Comment: $y_p$ is an odd function @ConradG  $y_p(x)=-y_p(-x)$

Comment: Ahh i see, but what I still don't understand is why we have to multiply the guess by $x^{2}$. Why is not multiplying the guess by x alone sufficient. is it simply based on the fact that the sin  is reduced by  x and that guarantees the particular is in the homogenous solution as well

Comment: Because our guess is already part of the homogeneous solution.. @ConradG

Comment: If you multiply by $x$  only your guess is still part of the homogeneous solution so we need to multiply by $x^2$ @ConradG

Comment: Note that also $x^2 \cos x$ cant be a guess since it"s an even function . So we need to try $x^3 \cos x$ this function is odd @ConradG

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out. I didn't know that odd function guess can be simplified. Therefore, if terms are repeated, then the solution must be raised by an additional power of x

Comment: You"re very welcome. @ConradG